# How to automate slide creation from an Excel file?

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

Quick question on slide automation in Excel / PowerPoint.

**Here is the setup:**

- Every month, I need to fill a PowerPoint
- In it, I have 5 slides per country, for 30 countries. On each slide, there is from 1 to 3 charts
- I use data from a pivot table in Excel to populate those charts and would like to automate the process

**What I have already done:**

- The automation in VBA to extract data from the Pivot Table has been done, everything is fine on this side

**What needs to be done:**

- Copy/paste the data from the Excel file inside the corresponding chart in the PowerPoint

**What I was thinking to do, either:**

- Copy paste the data directly into the chart, but is it even possible?
- Create a chart in the Excel file and copy paste it into PowerPoint (it cannot be a picture, the data behind the chart has to be accessible)

What do you think is the easiest way to do this?

EDIT: I am on Mac, did not know VBA / Office would be different but it is...

Comment: Did you try insert> table> Excel spreadsheet. and linking it to the spread sheet you're using?

Comment: If you are used to working in VBA then from your VBA project in Excel you can add a reference to the Microsoft PowerPoint Object Library. With that you might be able to find a way to create a new powerpoint presentation and add in the relevant data.

Comment: Try to "Record Macro".  I think that's the term.  You can record the actions you do via the Excel and PowerPoint GUIs.  That might help you.

Comment: @aFast, I tried to copy paste special the chart (not the table) and were able to change the data in PowerPoint by changing the data directly in Excel, which was great. But when I closed both files, it seems the link broke as when I put new data in the Excel file, they were not updated automatically anymore in PowerPoint. Maybe I' doing something wrong here though.

Comment: @RonRoyston, the macro recorder did not do great in this case, only had impractical results but thanks!

Comment: try www.pptxbuilder.com

Answer (score 1):

I would go for the second option.
Since you have performed already the automation for the pivot table, this may lead you to write what you want for. 
Note: as commented, you'd need to add a reference for Microsoft Power Point in order to be available to use the following:

```
Dim PPInstance As PowerPoint.Application
Dim PPSlide As PowerPoint.Slide
Dim SlideShow As PowerPoint.Presentation
    For Each SlideShow In PPInstance.Presentations
    On Error GoTo Err01PowerPoint_Select
    Set PPInstance = GetObject(, "Powerpoint.Application")
    If SlideShow.Name = "DesiredValue" Then '1. If SlideShow.Name = "DesiredValue"
    For Each PPSlide In SlideShow.Slides
    ' paste and select the chart picture
     ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(YourChartObjectInExcel).Copy
     Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
     'It may lost itself
     .Shapes.Paste
     Application.CutCopyMode = False
     'align the chart
     'you can definetly align and set the size you desire for the chart in PP, however, I didn't manage to make it work, you may want to search for it
     'PPInstance.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Align msoAlignCenters, True
     'PPInstance.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Align msoAlignMiddles, True
    Next PPSlide
    Exit For
    Next SlideShow
    If 1 = 2 Then '99.if error
    Err01PowerPoint_Select:
    MsgBox "No Powerpoint presentations are opened!", vbCritical
    End If '99.if error
```

Comment: Thanks I will look into that!

Comment: Just read you're on Mac, not quite sure this would work there

Comment: it's crazy, why it couldn't be working fine on both platform, damn... Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

- In excel copy the cells you want in your presentation
- Go back to power point and make a "past special" (home tab> past drop down> past special or `Cntrl+Alt+V`).
- choose [image: choose this option]

this should insert a linked table into your slide

### When you want to update

Go to: file> info

And choose

[image]

from the bottom right

Next do this

[image]

Comment: Thanks but I have some issues with this methods. After having copied the chart, I paste special in PowerPoint and have the following option: paste as a Microsoft Excel Chart Object or paste as a Microsoft Office Graphic Object. If I choose the first option, I cannot find the "Edit link to files" option (I m on Mac) to update the data. If I choose the second option, the data in PowerPoint gets updated whenever I change the data in the table in Excel but as soon as I close both files, the link is broken. Is there something else I should do? Thanks!

Comment: I think the function is missing from the Mac version of Office... Damn...

Comment: @PixAndCo how many tables do you have? i think if you right click on each table and choose edit or open it'll update. but this needs to be done for each table (i think)

Comment: thanks for the tip! There would be like 300 tables so it's not practical. If at least by updating one, the rest would follow, but no... :-(

Comment: check this out [Office 2011 for Mac: Copying Excel Charts to Word or PowerPoint](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/office-2011-for-mac-copying-excel-charts-to-word-o.html)

Comment: I tried but I have the same issue. If I select "Chart (Linked to Data)", it works (I change the data in Excel and it's updated directly into PowerPoint) but when I close the Excel file and reopen it, it doesn't work anymore. If I select "Excel Chart (entire workbook)", I can only change the data by right clicking on the graph in PowerPoint, click on "Edit Data in Excel" which opens a file called "Chart in Microsoft Office PowerPoint" but I cannot do a lot with that file. Thanks for the tip though.

Answer (score 0):

You are wanting to automate between MS Office applications, Excel and Powerpoint.  Microsoft uses the term programatically so a Web search for [Programatically excel to powerpoint](https://www.google.com/search?q=Programatically%20excel%20to%20powerpoint) should get you started.  You might add VBA to the search.

Comment: Thanks I looked into that. The link keeps breaking between Excel and PowerPoint (I m on Mac) and I have no idea why. I never have the pop up asking me to update the data when I open the PowerPoint file, even after having pasted special the chart into PowerPoint...